# How to log each value of the dropdown on change

Tags: javascript, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I have this piece of code, I'm trying to log the selected value of the dropdown but for some reason only "1" get logged. How to fix this?

```
  var select = document.getElementById("numOfPieces"); 
  var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; 
  
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
  }

  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);

  select.onchange = function() {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You are grabbing the value before onChange even called, but you should use the value after the onChange event.

```
select.onchange = function(e) {
  // change
  let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

when you are taking the value of `select.selectedIndex` before the event then its value is `0` that's why it always gives you the value of the element at `0` index.

Instead what you should do is to get the `select.selectedIndex` value after the `change` event gets triggered.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("numOfPieces");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}


select.onchange = function(e) {
  // change
  let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select name="numOfPieces" id="numOfPieces"></select>
```

**2)** You can also achieve the same result using `addEventListener`

```js
var select = document.getElementById("numOfPieces");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}

select.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(value);
})
```

```html
<select name="numOfPieces" id="numOfPieces"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the `var value`, not value from your onChange function. If you want to get the value from your select you need to change your function to receive the onChange event.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("selectField");
select.addEventListener(
   'change',
   function() { console.log(this.value); },
   false
);
```

```html
<select name="selectField" id="selectField">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

or

```js
const select = document.getElementById("selectField");
select.onchange = function() { console.log(this.value); };
```

```html
<select name="selectField" id="selectField">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This way the value you are printing refer to the `this` keyword, which inside the context refers to the select element.

Comment: It would be easy to understand for OP and other people who come on this post if you make this code runnable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up man. Will keep it in mind in the future.